# Any unique combination in SQL result

Tags: sql

```
Sample_Table
----------------
Col_1     Col_2
----------------
String A    AX
String B    VI
String C    MC
String D    MC
String E    AX
String F    AE
String G    AX
```

For the above table, I need to distinct values of Col_2 with Col_1.
I need my result to be like this.

```
String A    AX
String B    VI
String C    MC
String F    AE
```

I tried with following sql but did not achieve what i am looking for.

select distinct Col_1, Col_2 from sample_table;

select distinct Col_2 from sample_table;  (in this it only returns Col_2 values but not Col_1)

Any suggestions?

Comment: you could do this easy as pie with two ArrayList<String>() s (in Java and other languages), but no clue how SQL works. Do you *need* it to be a table with two columns?

Comment: Which column(s) determine the ordering here?  For example, for `AX` how do we know that string `A` is "less" than string `G`?

Comment: @ColeHenrich do i need to use that function in my SQL query?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Well, in this case ordering does not matter.

Comment: nvm! WOW! You got Gordon Linoff to answer your question! Ummm...that should be good!

Comment: why not simply `GROUP BY Col_1, Col_2` ? Your stated results don't make sense to me;  ALL of the column combos are distinct, and how do you choose which ones to exclude?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
select min(Col_1), Col_2
from sample_table
group by col_2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Col_2 ORDER BY Col_1) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT Col_1, Col_2
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

This answer is ideal because if, at some later time, you do have the requirement for choosing a given `Col_2` record based on some ordering, you would need only to modify the above `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: This Worked and the below, using aggregation also worked. Thank you!